# How to specify custom database-connection parameters for testing purposes in Play Framework v2?

Tags: unit-testing, postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

I want to run my tests against a distinct PostgreSQL database, as opposed to the in-memory database option or the default database configured for the local application setup (via the `db.default.url` configuration variable).  I tried using the `%test.db` and related configuration variables (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477330/playframework-evolutions-files-compatible-with-both-postgres-and-h2)), but that didn't seem to work; I think those instructions are intended for Play Framework v1.

FYI, the test database will have it's schema pre-defined and will not need to be created and destroyed with each test run.  (Though, I don't mind if it is re-created and destroyed with each test run, but I don't want to use "evolutions" to do so; I have a single SQL schema file I'm using at this point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [alternative configuration files](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ProductionConfiguration) while  local development to override DB credentials (and other settings) ie. like described in the [other answer (Update 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284312/playframework-2-storing-your-credentials/12290415#12290415).

Tip: using different kinds of databases in development and production leads fast to errors and bugs, so it's better to install the same DB locally for development and testing.

Comment: FYI, I'm not using "different kinds" of databases, or even different schemas, just different databases (so dev data doesn't get molested by the test suite).  Anyway, I went with a command-line override of the config param: `play -Ddb.default.url="postgres://dbuser:pass@localhost/testdb" test`.  Then I threw that command into a shell script for easy execution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We were able to implement Play 1.x style configs on top of Play 2.x - though I bet the creators of Play will cringe when they hear this.

The code is not quite shareable, but basically, you just have to override the "configuration" method in your GlobalSettings: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/scala/index.html#play.api.GlobalSettings

You can check for some system of conf setting like "environment.tag=%test" then override all configs of for "%test.foo=bar" into "foo=bar".